# Facebook API : Make profile picture for page - help needed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It is possible to select a picture from an album and put it as profile picture for my fan pages  with the facebook graph api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't even upload to the users profile picture album.

> You can upload to a specific user's album by calling photos.getAlbums.
>   However, you cannot upload to a user's profile picture album.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload/

Answer (score 0):

**No** it's not possible. Here is the official [`Page` object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) document to check what can be done.

Comment: According to this document it should be possible https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/picture/